Orthogonality of the character of rotation group
I am currently reading the book 'Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics' by Michael Tinkham and there's something I don't quite get. To show the completeness of the irreducible representations of the rotation group in section 5-5, the character of a rotation by $\alpha$ is shown to be
$$ \chi^{(j)}(\alpha)=\sum_m U_{mm}^{(j)}(\alpha) = \sum_{m=-j}^j e^{im\alpha}$$
for each irreducible representation $j$. The equation is understandable up to this point, but I want to know how the characters of different irreducible representations are orthogonal to each other. Do I integrate $\sum_{m=-j}^j (e^{im\alpha})^*$ with $\sum_{m=-j'}^{j'} e^{im\alpha}$ along all angle $\alpha$?

Unfortunately it is more complicated, you need to integrate over all group elements, so that involves $3$ parameters. This could be the Euler angles, or the axis of rotation (two parameters) and angle of rotation (one parameter).
So the integral you will get is:
$$
\int_\text{SU(2)}d\Omega\ \chi^{*(j)}\!(\Omega)\  \chi^{(j')}\!(\Omega)
$$
where $\Omega$ somehow represents the three parameters of the group and $d\Omega$ is the "invariant volume element" for the group.
Things are simplified by the fact that for the problem at hand the integrand only depends on the angle of rotation. Still the integral over different axes of rotation matters for what a "volume element" in the group actually means.
For infinitesimal angles, for instance, the rotation is close to the group's unit element and varying the rotation axis cannot change it very much. This is the same for angles close to $2\pi$. For that reason the volume element picks up a factor dependent on the angle of rotation. Detailed analysis (see below) gives this as $\sin^2\!{\large \frac\alpha 2}$. Knowing that, we can now integrate the characters:
$$
\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\!\sin^2\!{\small \frac\alpha 2}\ \, d\alpha\ \,
  \chi^{*(j)}\!(\alpha)\ \,\chi^{(j')}\!(\alpha)
$$
and with the normalization as chosen, the result is $\delta_{jj'}$ for all integer and half-integer $j$ and $j'$.
You can find more information in earlier discussions like [answer 1187641] and [answer 283846] or in this [wikipedia
] description.
EDIT: Based on the discussion in the comments, here the code to check a few results with [this engine]
Wolfram Language 14.1.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2024 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= X[j_,alpha_]=Sum[Exp[I m alpha],{m,-j,j}] //Simplify                                                           
              I (alpha + 2 alpha j)
        -1 + E
Out[1]= ---------------------------
         I alpha j        I alpha
        E          (-1 + E       )

In[2]:= j=5; jp=5; 1/(Pi) Integrate[Sin[a/2]^2 X[j,a] X[jp,a],{a,0,2Pi}]                                                
Out[2]= 1

In[3]:= j=1; jp=5; 1/(Pi) Integrate[Sin[a/2]^2 X[j,a] X[jp,a],{a,0,2Pi}]                                                
Out[3]= 0

In[4]:= j=1; jp=3/2; 1/(Pi) Integrate[Sin[a/2]^2 X[j,a] X[jp,a],{a,0,2Pi}]                                              
Out[4]= 0

In[5]:= j=2; jp=2; 1/(Pi) Integrate[Sin[a/2]^2 X[j,a] X[jp,a],{a,0,2Pi}]                                                
Out[5]= 1

In[6]:= j=1/2; jp=1/2; 1/(Pi) Integrate[Sin[a/2]^2 X[j,a] X[jp,a],{a,0,2Pi}]                                            
Out[6]= 1


I think this answer gave me a lot of clue but when I try integrating different characters using the formula above I don't get orthogonality, and I notice that the formula for character in answer 283846 involves integrating from 0 to pi, and the exponent in the summation changes by 2 instead of 1. The orthogonality seems to be restored when I change $\sin^2{x}$ to $\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$, but would that make sense?

You are absolutely right. I'm puzzled how this typo could have entered since I remember I did check it with Wolfram for a few values... I edited the answer (also adjusting the norm, and this time adding the 'check code'!)
